# Assigning a variable with a document.write() property makes it undefined why

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign a variable a string value using document.write but it's value is coming out as undefined.

This is what i am trying to do:

```
 var c;
    c=document.write("hello world"); 
    document.write(c);
```

Here i am getting output undefined please help me out i am new to javascript.

Comment: You need to read more on the basics of JavaScript. You wouldn't use `document.write()` to assign; in fact these days you wouldn't use `document.write()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

document.write() doesn't return a value.

[image]

Usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Perhaps you are aiming for this:

```
var c = "Hello World";
document.write(c);
var d = c; //pointless mapping to another variable, but shows how to get the original value.
```

Comment: Suppose you wanted the value of your variable the value of c?                                                                       d=document.write(c)

Comment: You woud do `var d = c`. Remember that `document.write()` never returns anything. I've amended my answer to show this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assign a value to variable c first, then document.write that value. Use document.write only till you are trying to learn the basics of javascript. Never beyond that unless code actually requires you to do so.

```
 var c;
    c="hello world"; 
    document.write(c);
```

Comment: thanks fro you answer i just wanted to know that why this undefined behaviour was taking place

Answer (score 1):

```
var c;
c= "hello world"; 
document.write(c);
```

this might work